# Can't restore SQL Server db from full backup, log processing fails, database in 'restoring' state

Tags: sql-server, restore, sql-server-2014, transaction-log

I am trying to set up a database for development purposes on my PC's local SQL Server Developer Edition 12.0.2000.8. I've got a full database backup and separate transaction-log-only backup files available which were sent to me over the network.

When trying to restore from full backup, after some time (~1 hour maybe, the database is ~270 GB in size), I'm getting an error :

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlError: An error occurred while processing the
>   log for database 'database name'.  If possible, restore from backup.
>   If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the
>   log. (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended)

After this, the db is in 'Restoring..' state.

I wanted to run something like (got it from [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/854/rebuilding-the-transaction-log) question)

```
ALTER DATABASE recovery_test_2 SET EMERGENCY;
ALTER DATABASE recovery_test_2 SET SINGLE_USER;

DBCC CHECKDB (recovery_test_2, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS;
```

against it, but naturally I can't as the database is in 'Restoring.." state.
Restarting the restore process on it leads to the same error message, dropping and restoring again didn't help too.

How do I get the db up and working? Transactional consistency doesn't matter to me.

The SSMS auto-generated restore script :

```
  USE [master]
  RESTORE DATABASE [database_name] FROM  DISK = N'D:\database_name.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,
  MOVE N'database_name' TO N'D:\MSSQL\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\database_name.mdf',
  MOVE N'database_name_index' TO N'D:\MSSQL\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\database_name_index.ndf',
  MOVE N'database_name_log' TO N'D:\MSSQL\MSSQL12.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\database_name_log.ldf',
  NOUNLOAD,
  STATS = 5

  GO
```

The result of query suggested by @Craig Efrein

> The log cannot be rebuilt because there were open transactions/users 
>   when the database was shutdown, no checkpoint occurred to the
>   database,  or the database was read-only. This error could occur if
>   the transaction log  file was manually deleted or lost due to a
>   hardware or environment failure.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64631/discussion-on-question-by-evictednoise-cant-restore-sql-server-db-from-full-bac).

Answer (score 2):

From the comments moved to chat, this note from the OP:

I just tried attaching it via GUI. As I selected the .mdf file, the SSMS identified the database consisted of 3 files (data, index, log), but somehow even though I was restoring WITH MOVE, the database details about file path were saying it wrong! So I just pointed them at the old log/data/index file and... The database is online.

Answer (score -3):

Change to single user mode and restore.

example :
The first restore uses the NORECOVERY option so additional restores can be done.  The second command restores the transaction log and then brings the database online for end user use.

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.BAK'
WITH NORECOVERY
GO
RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks FROM DISK = 'C:\AdventureWorks.TRN'
WITH RECOVERY
GO
```

Comment: The question references a single RESTORE DATABASE statement, no separate transaction log restore is being done. It's likely that the source database and/or backup file is corrupt.